Why is the background image in my code not fitting up the screen completely?
I've written a code in React JS and used Tailwind CSS to insert a background image in my code but the image is not filling up to the whole screen. Instead, the image has a margin of the same size on all sides and I don't know how to fix it.
Screenshot of how the image looks:

Here is the code where I insert the image:
<div className="w-full h-screen flex flex-wrap justify-center items-center bg-cover object-fill bg-no-repeat"
   style={{
       backgroundImage: `url('bg-image.png')`,
   }}
        
> </div>

I want the image to fit the screen completely  and not leave a white margin.

Try using the Browser DevTools to see the size of each element.

Could you please include the html you have before you div you have already included?

I bet you have a parent with container class, but as mentioned before, if we dont have the code we cant help

Can you please provide the parent Element of the code you mentioned earlier? Once you provide that, I should be able to help you fix it. What I noticed is that since you used display: flex, justify-content: center, and align-items: center, obviously it should act like the screenshot you sent

Maybe you need to add "background-size" with a value of "cover".
I did a little demo for you (first div is without background-size cover, second div has it):


*{
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

div{
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;

  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  
  border: 1px solid darkgray;
}

div:nth-child(1){
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/300/225);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

div:nth-child(2){
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/300/225);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

pre{
  font-size: small;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}
<div>
  <pre>background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/300/225);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;</pre>
</div>

<div>
  <pre>background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/300/225);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;</pre>
</div>




Thank you for this answer!! But i had already used bg-cover property in my code. I was using React JS so the problem was with a css file which is pre-loaded whenever you start a react project. I just figured that out recently.
